# Is any warning @ignore in this case?

Tags: dart

I have `Avoid redundant argument values.` warning in my code, and it is okay for that moment. Is there any @ignore option in dart for that?

Comment: You can add `// ignore: avoid_redundant_argument_values` or just disable that lint entirely.  See https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options.

Answer (score 0):

DON'T pass an argument that matches the corresponding parameter's default value.